# How to mass update id value pairs (group queries) in Laravel mysql query builder in a single database call?

Tags: laravel

I have one array for example named userValues;
It has 1000 items and a structure of

```
[
   {userId: string; value: number;}
]
```

I don't want to run a loop over this array and issue 1000 update operations of the type :
`update users set value=:value where id = :id`

Instead I would like to group them into a single statement something like

```
update users set value=1 where id = 1;
update users set value=223322 where id = 2;
# and so on for all the items in the array
```

How to achieve something like this in Laravel with the eloquent query builder?

For the moment I can run only 1000 separate update queries like this

```
    public function __construct(
        private DatabaseManager $db   
)

    public function example(): void
    {
          // just example with one value. In real usage this is coming from data source and the array contains million of entries
          $userValues = [
            (object)[
                'userId' => '34k4j32k34j0',
                'value' => 32423
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($userValues as $el) {
            $this->db->table('users')
                ->where('id', '=', $el->userId)
                ->update([
                    'value' => $el->value,
                ]);
        }
    }
```

The above of course works correctly and "gets the job done" but the performance implication is horrible. You send N (1000 in this simple example) separate update queries to the db

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do something like this example:

```
UPDATE users
SET value = 1
WHERE id in (1,2,3,....);
```

But I'm not sure if you can do something like what you are willing to do. If got your question right you are trying to do something like:

```
UPDATE users
SET value = (a list of data like: [1,22,3,...])
WHERE id in (a list of id's like: (1,2,3,...))
```

And that because when you are doing an update, the rows affected should be logically connected with each other. Again If i got it right, by the condition you are trying to do the update for example updating the first user value to one(value=1) and the second user value = 2 means they are not related with each other. And there should be executed 2 separated queries. However if you are trying to set the same value for more than one user then the update can be performed using only one query. Same as the first example I showed. Don't forget the fact that performance is an issue when the user of you application is trying to reach your database. In this case is this a query he would do in you application or is it just you trying to populate the database with data?

If this doesn't answer your question, write down the SQL query you are trying to build using laravel.

Comment: Hi, yes you got it right. I am aware of the first query to update many rows based on `where id in (1,2,3,4)` but that will set the value to same value for all of the rows. I ended up issuing multiple update statements in one go. `update set value = 1 where user_id=1; update set value=2 where user_id=2;` and so on just concatenated the strings and executed a raw query

Comment: That I was trying to say in my answer, one query can update only rows that are related from the where condition. Anyway when you try to write query builder with Laravel, first make sure you can do such a thing on the database part. And that because Laravel query builder can perform only queries that are supported from the database you are using. Hope you find this helpful.